# Hidden form values are empty when viewed through Firefox

Tags: c#, html, firefox, firefox-addon, hidden-field

I am trying to post a Contact Us Form, there are few hidden type fields and when tried to post, the values are not obtained in FF. Hidden form values are empty when viewed through Firefox Inspect Element, but the same hidden values has the values in it when viewed through View Page Source. Please find the screenshot.[image]

The value is empty for some of the hidden fields only(Campaign and LeadSource values are empty). What am I missing here? Can someone help me.